# google-bigquery Is there a way to copy a table and have it be updated when the original is?

Tags: google-bigquery

Basically we have a lot of tables throughout several datasets but only want to share a few of the tables with people and the only way for access control is on a dataset level so the idea was to make a copy of the tables we wanted to show in a new dataset that would be dynamically updated when the original was. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to create a table that updates based on another table's contents. The best way to do this is to define a logical view, which is treated similarly to a table. If you want to give access to all columns in the underlying table, you can define your view (make sure to use standard SQL) as:

```
SELECT * FROM `your-project.your_dataset.table_name`;
```

If the target table is partitioned, you can define a view that exposes the partitioning column:

```
 SELECT *, DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) AS partition_date
 FROM `your-project.your_dataset.table_name`;
```

The view will stay up to date with whatever the contents of the underlying table are.